# Change DIV in one remove/append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I am doing, I create a div structure dynamically

```
    var divt = $('<div id="toplevel"></div>');
divt.append('<div id="child1"><div class="content1"></div></div>');
divt.append('<div id="child2"><div class="content1"></div></div>');
```

I then store a clone to a separate node and add it to the DOM.

```
this.emptydivt = $(divt).clone();
maindiv.append(divt);
```

Later on in my code I want to replace the contents of the top level DIV using one remove/append.

Firstly I create a new node from my previously saved...

```
this.newdivt = this.emptydivt.clone();
```

Here I want to get the child divs and append some new content , I have tried various function but can't get it to work eg.

```
var childdiv = this.newdivt.find('#child1').html(); 
childdiv.append('<div> new content</div>');
```

then after I will replace the top level div

```
maindiv.remove('#toplevel');
maindiv.append(this.newdivt);
```

So is there a way to get the child div from a Jquery or JS node that is not in the DOM ?

Comment: Check your console, i'm sure you should see error. What is property clone? What about `var childdiv = $(this.newdivt.find('#child1').html()); ` Etc...

Comment: `this.emptydivt = $(eventGrid).clone(divt);` is not correct, what are you trying to do here

Comment: On the clone functions I don't get an error and the results look correct. When I try and get to the child nodes they stay "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 typos in your code, not sure if on your real code they are not present

```
this.newdivt = this.emptydivt.clone();  // you missed ()
```

and

```
var childdiv = this.newdivt.find('#child1').html(); // you missed '' around #child1
```

Also, this code is not valid as `clone` doesn't accept a jQuery object as parameter

```
this.emptydivt = $(eventGrid).clone(divt);
```

Maybe you just want `divt.clone()`?

**EDIT**

Remove all white spaces on your elements ids as white spaces are not allowed on id attribute.

Comment: @FlyingScotsman: if all the typos we pointed out aren't in your real code, please fix them on the question to avoid confusions.

Comment: @FlyingScotsman: there is an extra one, you're not closing your divs on your first 2 append `'<div id="child1"><div class="content1"><div><div>'`and `'<div id="child2"><div class="content1"><div><div>'`

Comment: @FlyingScotsman: something else you need to clarify is what you're trying to do here `$(eventGrid).clone(divt)` as it is not valid code.

Comment: I have corrected these in the question, I hope the syntax is okay now, like I said in the real code all works fine, except for the parsing of the node outside the DOM.

Comment: No but the child nodes do, I just checked and if I remove the spaces the find . html works, do you know why ?

Comment: Also the html function gives in child1 contents so  <div class="content1"></div> what I was looking for was a pointer to <div id="child1"><div class="content1"></div></div>.